# Perl: How to count number of times 3-word phrase (with gaps) occurs within an N-word window

Tags: perl

I'm trying to count the number of times a 3-word phrase occurs within a 12-word window in a document, but the difficulty is that the keywords I'm searching for can be spread throughout the window.

For example:

I want to find the phrase "expect bad weather" within a 12-word phrase, where other words can be inserted between the 3 desired words as long as the total phrase in which the 3 words are contained does not exceed 12 words.

Phrases which would work:

- I expect there will be bad weather.
- They expect bad and windy weather.
- I expect, although no one has confirmed this, that bad weather is on
  the way.

I've struggled to figure out how to do this. I know how to count occurrences of 2-word phrases where there can be a gap between. For example, if I'm counting how often "expect" and "weather" occur within a 12-word phrase, I can do:

```
$mycount =()= $text =~ /\b(?:expect\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,10}?weather)\b/gi;
```

However, it's not as simple when I want to do this with 3 words, because I end up with 2 gaps which must sum together so that my window doesn't exceed 12 words. Ideally I would be able to do something like:

```
$mycount =()= $text =~ /\b(?:expect\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,$Gap1}?bad\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,$Gap2}?weather)\b/gi;
```

Where $Gap2 = 9 - $Gap1, but I don't think there's a way to do this.

I also thought of creating a loop so that in one iteration of the loop, $Gap1=0 and $Gap2=9, in the second iteration $Gap1=1 and $Gap2=8, etc, and then adding the counts of all of the loops. However, doing this will doublecount some instances of the phrase.

I'm at a loss. Does anyone have any ideas? I can't find any relevant examples anywhere.

Comment: Does your window start with the first phrase (when all three happen to be found then)? And if they are not found wihtin 12 words then you "reset" and start a "provisional" window again when you run into the first word?

Comment: Yes, the first word in the phrase starts the window.

Comment: Thank you. Can there be multiple occurrences of the phrase within the whole string?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple occurrences, which is why I want to count them. For example, say all 3 example phrases I gave above are in the same document, which I slurp into the $text variable. I want to be able to count that there are 3 occurrences of the phrase.

Comment: I tested the posted code but surely not well enough -- let me know if you find holes in thorough tests.

Comment: Looks like you need to parse instead of simply match. Also it's unclear if you need to look for the difference between "Good thing I expect bad weather", and "Good thing I expect no bad weather at all". You're lucky there's a bunch of people willing to write you a parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**    This post addresses the question of finding words spread out within a window, as asked. It does not consider the far more involved issues of general text parsing or language analysis.

---

The code below searches for the first word and then continues with another regex for the other two. There it scans the text word by word and keeps a counter so it can stop at 12 words. It uses `pos` to control where it should continue after checking the window.

The 12-long window is taken to start with word `expect` once it is found, as clarified in comments. The search continues from after the completed phrase, for the next one.

If the phrase is not found within the next 11 words the engine is returned to the position after `expect` to carry on with the search (as there may be another `expect` within the checked 11 words).

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $s = q(I expect, although no one confirmed, that bad weather is on the way.)
      . q(  Expect that we cannot expect to escape the bad, bad weather.);

my $word_range = 12;
my ($w1, $w2, $w3) = qw(expect bad weather);

FIRST_WORD: while ($s =~ /\b($w1)\b/gi) {
    #say "SEARCH, at ", pos $s;
    my ($one, $pos_one) = ($1, pos $s);

    my ($two, $three, $cnt);

    while ($s =~ /(\w+)/g) {
        my $word = $1; 
        #say "\t$word  ... (at ", pos $s, ")";

        $two = $1  if $word =~ /\b($w2)\b/i; 
        
        if ( $two and (($three) = $word =~ /\b($w3)\b/i) ) { 
            say "$one + $two + $three  (pos ", pos $s, ')';
            next FIRST_WORD;
        }
        last if ++$cnt == $word_range-1;  # failed (these 11 + 'expect') 
    }
    pos $s = $pos_one;         # return to position in string after 'expect'
}
```

Note that one cannot assign the match (for `$one`) inside the loop condition as that puts the matching in the list context and thus disturbs the needed behavior of `/g` and [pos](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html).

The prints which are commented out can be used to track the operation.  As it stands this prints

```
expect + bad + weather  (pos 53)
Expect + bad + weather  (pos 128)
```

I extend the string to test multiple occurrences of the phrase. The operation with failed matches can be tested by crippling keywords and tracking the position in the search.

A possible extra keyword inside of the phrase, as in the second sentence, is ignored and the phrase is accepted if there, as this is unspecified but implicit in the question. This is easily changed.

If there were more words in the phrase they would all be sought in the inner `while` loop, in the same way as the last two are now, by matching them sequentially (requiring for each word that all preceding words had been found). The outer `while` loop is needed only to start the window.

---

After a failed window-scan the outer `while` continues its search for `expect` from the position of the window beginning, thus scanning the same 11 words again.

This repeated search through the text can be reduced by checking for `expect` as well during the window scan. Then scan afresh from that position, with the inner `while`

```
# First sentence shortened and now does not contain the phrase
my $s = q(I expect, although no one confirmed, that bad expect.)
      . q( Expect that we cannot expect to escape the bad, bad weather.);    
...
FIRST_WORD: while ($s =~ /\b($w1)\b/gi) {
    my ($one, $pos_one) = ($1, pos $s);

    my ($two, $three, $cnt, $pos_one_new);

    while ($s =~ /(\w+)/g) {
        my $word = $1;
        #say "\t$word  ... (at ", pos $s, ")";

        $pos_one_new = pos $s
            if not $pos_one_new and $word =~ /\b$w1\b/i;

        $two = $1  if $word =~ /\b($w2)\b/i;

        if ( $two and (($three) = $word =~ /\b($w3)\b/i) ) {
            say "$one + $two + $three  (pos ", pos $s, ')';
            next FIRST_WORD;
        } 

        if (++$cnt == $word_range-1) {
            last  if not $pos_one_new;
     
            #say "Scan window anew from $pos_one_new";
            pos $s   = $pos_one_new;
            $pos_one = $pos_one_new;
            $pos_one_new = 0;
            $two = $three = '';
            $cnt = 0;
        }
    }
    pos $s = $pos_one;
}
```

This prints

```
expect + bad + weather  (pos 113)
```

Note that the *first* occurrence of `expect` within the window is used.

Comment: @elci  Updated with two bug fixes: (1)  "badly" is matched by "bad" (etc) when without `\b` around `($wN)` (2) In the nested re-scanning of the window the `$two` and `$three` need be reset as well

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned processing a document, I assume you're working with a long string of sentences.  So you could have:

> I am unsure why I always expect bad from people. Weather isn't an
>   indicator.

I assume that this would NOT be desirable to mark as an occurrence of the target phrase "expect bad weather".

You've already got one great answer that is purely regex oriented. You could easily fix the cross sentence phrase detection bug it features by splitting on the sentence, like I do here. Despite that, I thought I'd show another way to think about the problem.

The key concepts are **tokenize** and **normalize**.

First we turn the corpus into a list of sentences.  That's tokenization level one.

Seconds we turn each sentence into a string of lower case words with punctuation (except apostrophe) removed.  Tokenization level two and normalization.

Now all you have to do is sift through all your piles of tokens and see if any contain the target tokens.

I handle backtracking in a very lazy way by looping over the corpus text looking for places where we match the first word of our target.  Where that happens, I grab up to the maximum number of words from the corpus and check to see if the target list is contained in that list.  This gives a nice backtracking behavior without all the book-keeping.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use Lingua::Sentence;

my $doc = "I am unsure why I always expect bad from people. Weather isn't an indicator. My mood is fine whether it is sunny or I expect to see some bad weather.";

my @targets = (
    [qw/ expect bad weather /],
    [qw/ my mood is bad /],
);
my $max_phrase_length = 12;

my $splitter = Lingua::Sentence->new('en');
my @sentences = $splitter->split_array( $doc );

my %counter;

for my $sentence ( @sentences ) {
    say "Checking sentence:  $sentence";
    my @words = map lc,                  # Normalize to lowercase
                map /(['\w]*)/,          # get rid of punctuation
                split /\s+/, $sentence;  # Break sentence into words

    for my $target ( @targets ) {
        say "    Checking target:  @$target";

        for my $i (0..$#words ) { 
            my $word = @words[$i];
            say "        Checking $word";

            next if $word ne $target->[0];

            my $first_word = $i; 
            my $last_word = $i + $max_phrase_length -1; 
            $last_word = $#words if $last_word > $#words;

            if ( has_phrase( $target, [ @words[$first_word..$last_word] ] ) ) { 
                say "BINGO!  @$target";
                $counter{ "@$target" }++;
            }
        }
    }
}

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper \%counter;


sub has_phrase {
    my ( $target, $text ) = @_;
    return if @$target > $text;

    my $match_idx = 0;
    for my $idx ( 0..$#$text ) {
        if ($target->[$match_idx] eq $text->[$idx]) {
            $match_idx++;
            return 1 if $match_idx eq @$target;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Very nice to see a proper take on it. (I decided to "tokenize" on the fly via `while (/\w+/g)`.)   A note on the "_cross sentence phrase detection **bug**_" (my emphasis) -- that post disregards any language structure on purpose.  (Which would get into "bad weather" vs "no bad weather" issues. I specifically patch the phrase across "sentences," one of which is broken, in the second example.)  It parses a string for words within a window (and doesn't claim the absence of possible subtle bugs in that either :). All that said, perhaps I _should've_ broken the text into sentences first.

Comment: @zdim, you already had my upvote.  The OP only loosely implied that they might not want cross-sentence phrases (all the positive examples were only one sentence).  As I pointed out, it's easy to break out the sentences before handing the text to your example code.  At least as easy as finding sentences in English text ever is. :)  I do stand-by the use of the word bug, although it is a bug as much in specification as implementation.  In my decades of building software, these errors of the invisible assumption are the hardest to identify and fix.

Comment: Well, yes; this clearly seems to be about text so sentence structure should be respected and then it is a bug. It is a good point and a great post (upvoted already), I only meant to state my rationale. But you are right, if it's clear what it is I should've straightened it out. I completely agree with the assessment of "invisible assumptions."  A good deal of building software is about articulating "requirements" -- translating from the problem domain. It's a non-trivial problem and when communication fails on top of it (with unstated/invisible features) it's hard to get it straight.

Answer (score -1):

Your requirements are a little vague to me. Like I don't know if you want to take in any sequence of words, and then count "expect .* bad .* weather", or if you want to only take 12 words and ignore the rest, or if you want to slide along a word at a time and never look at more than 12 words at a time.

I figured I'd simplify it:
I take the whole line input; I throw out whatever words aren't expect, bad, or weather; then I count the number of "expect bad weather" occurrences thereafter. If something says "expect bad bad weather" That's not a match. I'm sure you can modify this with your more exact requirements AS you understand them better than I.

```
while(<>){
$_=lc;
@w=split(/\W+/);
@w=map {
  if    (/expect/)      {1}
  elsif (/bad/)         {2}
  elsif (/weather/)     {3}
  else                  {0}
  } @w;
$_ = join("", @w);
print;
@w=grep {+$_>0} @w;
$_ = join("", @w);
print "=>$_";
@r=/123/g;
print "=".scalar(@r)."\n";
}
```

Examples:

```
hi! Expect really bad weather man.
010230=>123=1
hi! Expect really bad weather man.hi! Expect really bad weather man.hi! Expect really bad weather man.
010230010230010230=>123123123=3
Expect expect bad weather, expect bad bad bad weather, expect bad expect weather.
1123122231213=>1123122231213=1
```

You can also sort of one-line this, but I think `scalar(/123/g)` means something different than `@r=/123/g;scalar @r;` so I put `scalar(@_=/123/g)`.

```
$ perl -nE '$_=lc;$_=join("",grep{+$_>0}map{if(/expect/){1}elsif(/bad/){2}elsif(/weather/){3}else{0}}split(/\W+/));say scalar(@_=/123/g)."\n";'
hi! Expect really bad weather man.
1

hi! Expect really bad weather man. hi! Expect really bad weather man.
2

Expect Sad and Bad Weather today. Maybe Expect bad weather tomorrow too, because scalar is not helping.
2
```

Comment: It's an answer that reframes how to process the input so that the person who knows the requirements, and isn't giving them clearly can easily adapt this to work.
I'm not sure why it would get down-voted other than that I'm not willing to do every last detail of someone else's work.